# getting error on desirializing java object from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization

I started to learn Kafka, and now,
I'm on sending/receiving serialized/desirialised java class.
My question is about: what have I missed in my config, so I can't deserialize the object from Kafka

here is my class:

> ```
> public class Foo { 
>     private String item;
>     private int quantity;
>     private Double price;
>   
>     public Foo(String item, int quantity, final double price) {
>         this.item = item;
>         this.quantity = quantity;
>         this.price = price;
>     }
>
>     public String getItem() { return item; }
>     public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
>     public Double getPrice() { return price; }
>
>     public void setQuantity(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }
>     public void setPrice(double price) { this.price = price; }
>
>     @Override
>     public String toString() {
>         return "item=" + item + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", price=" + price;
>     }
> }
> ```

my Properties in main class:

> producerPropsObject.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
> AppConfigs.applicationProducerSerializedObject);
> producerPropsObject.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
> AppConfigs.bootstrapServers);
> producerPropsObject.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
> StringSerializer.class.getName());
> producerPropsObject.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
> **FooSerializer.class.getName()**);
> producerPropsObject.put("topic", AppConfigs.topicNameForSerializedObject);

> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, AppConfigs.applicationProducerSerializedObject);
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, AppConfigs.bootstrapServers);
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,**FooDeserializer.class.getName()**);
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
> consumerPropsObject.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
> consumerPropsObject.put("topic", AppConfigs.topicNameForSerializedObject);

following are serializer/deserializer implementations:

> ```
> public class FooSerializer implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer {
>
>     public void configure(Map map, boolean b) { }
>
>     public byte[] serialize(String s, Object o) {
>         try {
>             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
>             oos.writeObject(o);
>             oos.close();
>             byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
>             return b;
>         } catch (IOException e) { return new byte[0]; }
>     }
>
>     public void close() {  }
> }
>
> public class FooDeserializer implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer {
>     
>     @Override
>     public void close() { }
>
>     @Override
>     public Foo deserialize(String arg0, byte[] arg1) {
>     
>         //Option #1:
>         //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>         //Option #2:
>         JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
>         factory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);
>         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
>         Foo fooObj = null;
>         try {
>             //Option #1:
>             //fooObj = mapper.readValue(arg1, Foo.class);     // BREAKS HERE!!!
>             //Option #2:
>             fooObj = mapper.reader().forType(Foo.class).readValue(arg1); // BREAKS HERE!!!
>     
>         }
>         catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
>     
>         return fooObj;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

and finally the way I'm trying to produce and consume my Foo from main:

seems, like it works fine, cause I see in kafka-topic my Key && Value later on

> ```
> public void produceObjectToKafka(final Properties producerProps) { 
>     final String[] ar = new String[]{"Matrix", "Naked Gun", "5th Element", "Die Hard", "Gone with a wind"};
>     KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps);
>     final Foo j = new Foo(ar[getAnInt(4)], getAnInt(10), getAnDouble());
>     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(producerProps.getProperty("topic"), j.getItem(), j.toString().getBytes()));
>     producer.flush();   
>     producer.close();
> }
> ```

however, while my Consumer is catching the output:

> ```
> public void consumeFooFromKafka(final Properties consumerProps) {
>     final Consumer<String, Foo> myConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
>     final Thread separateThread = new Thread(() -> {
>         try {
>             myConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(consumerProps.getProperty("topic")));
>             while (continueToRunFlag) {
>                 final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>                 final ConsumerRecords<String, Foo> consumerRecords = myConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
>                 if (consumerRecords.count() > 0) {
>                     for (ConsumerRecord<String, Foo> cRec : consumerRecords) {
>                         sb.append(  cRec.key()  ).append("<<").append(cRec.value().getItem() + ",").append(cRec.value().getQuantity() + ",").append(cRec.value().getPrice()).append("|");
>                    }
>                }
>                if (sb.length() > 0) { System.out.println(sb.toString()); }
>             }
>         }
>         finally {
>             myConsumer.close();
>         }
>     });
>     separateThread.start();
> }
> ```

=======================================
so, actually by running "consumeFooFromKafka" , when it trigger "FooDeserializer" ...... there, I always have same error(regardless of Option #1, or Option #2):

> exception:
> Method threw 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException' exception.
> detailedMessage:
> Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or
> 'false')

will be very appresiated for help.......
Thank you in advance,
Steve

Comment: have u try serializing using jackson also?

Comment: nope, I just followed online example from https://blog.knoldus.com/kafka-sending-object-as-a-message/ ... where is no word about that

Comment: it is failed because you serialize is not serializing to bytes of json, it is just bytes of your object, u need to serialize to json, thats why i recommend use jackson serializer

Comment: @rizesky JSON isn't needed. Kafka doesn't care as long as it's bytes

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is not kafka problem, please read the question, it is his deserializer problem, kafka is accepting his message in byte stream of his object, but it is not byte of json , it is byte of his java object which depend on his implementation to serializable interface(whether is overried of left default), thats why his json desealizer if failed to deserialize as it is require bytes of json to perform,  but he provide bytes of his java object. And if you still dont understand please read what is serialization. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deserialize from json, than u need to serialize it to json, use jackson in ur serializer also, and everything should be fine

```java
public class FooSerializer implements org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer {

    public void configure(Map map, boolean b) { }

    public byte[] serialize(String s, Object o) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();//objectmapper from jackson
            byte[] b = om.writeValueAsString(o).getBytes();
            return b;

        } catch (IOException e) { return new byte[0]; }
    }

    public void close() {  }
}
```

Comment: Guys, thanks alot for helping.... indeed I missed those 2 different ways of serialization...like I said: I just started...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using a bytearray outputstream, but trying to read JSON in the deserializer, but that explains the error. You could even test that without using Kafka at all by invoking the serialize/deserialize methods directly

In the link provided, the serializer uses `objectMapper.writeValueAsString`, which returns JSON text, and not the Java specific outputstream. If you wanted to consume and produce data between different programming languages (as is often the case in most companies), you'd want to avoid such specific serialization formats

Note: Confluent provides Avro, Protobuf, and JSON serializers for Kafka, so you shouldn't need to write your own if you want to use one of those formats

Comment: Agree, he maybe think serialization is creating json of that object. serializaton is just creating bytes sequence of serialized object to be able to store in disk or send it over socket